# How to select everything from first table where is based on third table

Tags: mysql, sql

Well guys I have the following model to explain(I dont have enough reputation to post image), I need query the table *ModelosEmUso* sending the *Carros* ID by the User, but I need the *ModeloPeca.modelo* and *ModeloPeca.quantidade* instead the FK from *ModelosEmUso*

I tried several queries but not succeful, I was think about join but I couldn't figure out how do it.

```
------------
|Carro     |
------------
|idCarro   |
|nome      |  
|catergoria|
-------------
    |
    | 
    |
    |
    |
   /|\
--------------------           ----------------
|ModelosEmUso      |           |ModeloPeca    |
--------------------           ----------------
|idModelosEmUso    |           |idPeca        |
|quantidadeRestante|__________<|modelo        |
|modeloPeca_idPeca |           |quantidade    |  
|carros_idCarros   |           |valor         |
--------------------           |/others coluns|
                               ----------------
```

PS: bad draw I know, the relationships are OneToMany non-indentifying.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you just want to do an inner join from ModelosEmUso to ModeloPeca. You don't need to join to Carro because you have carros_idCarros on ModelosEmUso to do your filtering. Maybe something like:

```
SELECT
     MP.modelo
    ,MP.quantidade
FROM ModelosEmUso ME
    INNER JOIN ModeloPeca MP
        ON ME.modeloPeca_idPeca = MP.idPeca
WHERE ME.carros_idCarros = @USER_PARAM
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select ModeloPeca.modelo, ModeloPeca.quantidade from ModeloPeca left join ModelosEmUso on ModeloPeca.idPeca = ModelosEmUso.modeloPeca_idPeca left join Carro On Carro.idCarro = <your user id>
```